# Problem with lists, polymorphism and casting in C#

Tags: c#, list, casting, polymorphism

Good afternoon, I am looking to transfer a list of objects that implement a certain interface ("IRecord"), what I do is to filter in a new list the objects that implement the interface in the following case "IEntry", until there is no problem, however, I have problems when I try to caste the filtered list to the type "IList" to use the properties that this last one has, this produces an exception, how can I solve this, Is there a way to avoid going through the whole list, and create a new one again?

```cs
interface IRecord
{
    string Details { get; set; }
}

interface IEntry : IRecord
{
    decimal TotalValue { get; set; }
}

interface IEgress : IRecord
{
    string Type { get; set; }
}

class Entry : IEntry
{
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalValue { get; set; }

    public void Foo() { }
}

class Egress : IEgress
{
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code I am trying to execute

```cs
var records = new List<IRecord>() { new Entry() { Details = "foo" }, new Egress() { Details = "bar" } };

var filteredList = records.Where(entry => entry is Entry).ToList();

var sum = (IList<IEntry>)filteredList;
var x = sum.Sum(en => en.TotalValue);
```

[image: Error Desc.]

Comment: You will never convert IRecord to IEntry, there is no inheritance, but an IEntry can be a IRecord. [About interface inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-inheritance-in-interfaces/)

Comment: @VilmarPavesi It's true, I don't know why I didn't reason it that way, however I was able to solve it with IEnumerable.Cast<T>(), method I didn't know, it fulfills what I wanted to do from the beginning.

Comment: you can Cast to the type first.
`var filteredList = records.Where(entry => entry is Entry).Cast<IEntry>().ToList();`

However as @VilmarPavesi has stated,  you might be misunderstanding inheritance.

Comment: you can also use `Enumerable.OfType` extension method to retrieve elements of a specific type: `var filteredList = records.OfType<Entry>().ToList();`. Then, you can do: `var sum = filteredList.ToList<IEntry>();`

Comment: @SecretSquirrel I definitely got mentally blocked trying to accomplish something in that way and only in that way, that I didn't get to think about the most basic fundamentals behind what I wanted to do, "IRecord" has no idea of the existence of "IEntry", I don't know how I intended to make it magically transform.

Comment: @RuslanGilmutdinov Thank you very much, I didn't know it either, I'm going to try it right now!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments you can `Cast` your query before calling `ToList()`

`var filteredList = records.Where(entry => entry is Entry).Cast<IEntry>().ToList();`

So the end result would be

```
var records = new List<IRecord>() 
{ 
    new Entry() { Details = "foo", TotalValue = 12 }, 
    new Egress() { Details = "bar" } 
};

var filteredList = records.Where(entry => entry is Entry).Cast<IEntry>().ToList();

var sum = (IList<IEntry>)filteredList;
var x = sum.Sum(en => en.TotalValue);
```

I added a value to your Entry type too, which then allows you to prove your code works :D

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance) is a link to Microsoft document on inheritance

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, the code is actually another one, I tried to make something as simple as possible to describe the problem I had, thank you very much again for your help.

Comment: why not just `records.OfType<IEntry>().ToList()`?